# Easily insert multiple numeric values into a query string

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a query that pulls multiple results from a proprietary DMS software.  The syntax is as follows:
{[Members]:[Acct No]="*numerical value 1*"} | {[Members]:[Acct No]="*numerical value 2*"} | ...

This can be repeated as many times as needed to pull back the documents with the requested account numbers.  I need a way to take account numbers from a list (about 1000 numbers) and format them into this query.

Any ideas?

Comment: it's not 100% clear what your trying to do. add some manual example or pseudo code. Just a note: off hand query strings are limited to be less then 4000 characters normally, so if the idea was to repeat that example structure 1000 times, it won't even come close to fitting in a query string.

Comment: if the list of account numbers is in a table, can you use a join between your data and the accou8nt number table to only select the account numbers you want?  Never mind, I'm thinking in  Access.  Sorry

Comment: DarrenMB, sorry I wasn't really clear in my original post.  The base syntax for the search is {[Members]:[Acct No]="1"}, where Members is the Metadata template name, Acct No is the field name that will be searched, and 1 is the account number searched for.  I will have a file that has a list of account numbers to search, so if my account numbers were 12345, 54321, and 98765, my final search string would look like: {[Members]:[Acct No]="12345"} | {[Members]:[Acct No]="54321"} | {[Members]:[Acct No]="98765"}  Hope that helps clarify.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to build a string from an array of numbers and "[Members]:[Acct No]="numerical value 1"}", then try:

```
>> a = Array(1, 3, 5)
>> p1 = "[Members]:[Acct No]=""numerical value "
>> p2 = """}|{"
>> p3 = "{"
>> p4 = """}"
>> WScript.Echo p3 & p1 & Join(a, p2 & p1) & p4
>>
{[Members]:[Acct No]="numerical value 1"}|{[Members]:[Acct No]="numerical value 3"}|{[Members]:[Acct No]="nume
rical value 5"}
```